# Dynamic subtraction of crosstab columns in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab

I'm working in Access with some Crosstab columns that are generated dynamically based on the reports received (eg: Based on the parameter year: 2009,2010,2011). I’d like to calculate the difference of two years consecutively for all the generated columns (eg:2009-10,10-11,….). Is there any way to do it?

Eg:
Default crosstab:
2009 2010 2011
A 30 20 5
B 30 20 5
Expected output:
2009 2010 2011 20010-2009 2011-10
A 30 20 5 -10 -15
B 30 20 5 -10 -15

I can easily created calculated fields and do this manually, but the data changes and I get additional years received in the data and want to make it dynamic.

Is there a way to do this in MS Access?

Comment: Most anything can be done with enough code. Might involve writing records to a 'temp' table.

Comment: Write a tabular example of your input data and desired output so we can understand your question.